# Why is limiting my trustAsHtml text to 140 chars having no effect?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to limit my trusted text to 140 chars but all the text is showing instead.  Any idea why?  The `limitTo:140` has no effect.

Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
    data.results[i].Description = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.results[i].Description);
    $scope.vehicles.push(data.results[i]);
}


<div class="child" ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
          <div data-ng-bind-html="vehicle.Description | limitTo:140"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, your answer looks like it makes perfect sense but I'm not able to get it working.  I've tried both methods.  The first didn't limit the text (no text was displayed) the second one gave me an `TypeError: dbg is undefined` error.

Comment: I have tried this and it works perfectly. Unless you show a demo showcasing the issue it would be really difficult to help.`TypeError: dbg is undefined`? where is it coming from. It must be from your code only... Also remember that you need to include ngSanitize to get ng-bind-html to work, Hope you are alreadt doing that.

Comment: Check this demo.. http://jsbin.com/rovacatizu/2/edit You don't even need to use $sce.trustAs if u use valueOf().

Comment: Thank you very much for the demo and the additional help.  I've got it working now, wasn't including ngSanitize.

Comment: Cool. And removed trustAsHtml part as well right?

Comment: Yeah I removed that part too - all working :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because limitTo filter takes `Source array, string or number to be limited.` But what you are providing to the filter is the trusted value which is an object which is expanded later during the binding. You can get the value using `$scope.vehicle.Description.valueOf()` which unwraps trusted value.

So you could either do:-

```
 <div data-ng-bind-html="vehicle.Description.valueOf() | limitTo:140"></div>
```

or you could as well apply filter directly on the Description, inject `limitToFilter` and do:-

```
 data.results[i].Description = 
         $sce.trustAsHtml(limitToFilter(data.results[i].Description, 140));
```

Note:- If you are using `ng-bind-html` you do not explicitly need to do `$sce.trustAsHtml` as the directive itself will be handling it internally so you could as well just remove the code:-

```
data.results[i].Description = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.results[i].Description);
```

and use it directly so that `Description` is no longer a `wrappedTrustedValue` object instead it is the string itself which will be limited and then parsed as html:-

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="vehicle.Description | limitTo:140"></div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/sivakehoji/1/edit)**